# Vue.js load component theme without Vue.use

Tags: vue.js, vue-select

I am using [Cool-Select](https://github.com/danieldocki/vue-cool-select) and it requires the following code to load its theme:

```
import VueSelect from 'vue-cool-select'
Vue.use(VueSelect, {
  theme:'material-design'
})
```

The problem is that I do not want to have to import the entire vue code in order to just use a theme. Also, the components works fini without the theme import; just missing css.

Is it possible to import the theme locally instead in the `components` part like this?

```
import { CoolSelect } from 'vue-cool-select'      
components:{
        CoolSelect,
        // import theme here
 },
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. What's VueSelect and why do you not want to use Vue.use, considering that it requires to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VueSelect` is a plugin, i.e. it has [`install` method](https://github.com/danieldocki/vue-cool-select/blob/master/src/main.js#L20) that will be called when provided to `Vue.use`. This doesn't affect the application except that it [loads styles that are specific to this component](https://github.com/danieldocki/vue-cool-select/blob/master/src/main.js#L26).

Since styles weren't exported from the package and are loaded only on plugin installation, this is the only way how `CoolSelect` component can have its styles loaded without forking the package:

```
Vue.use(VueSelect, {
  theme:'material-design'
})
```